# Deleting multiple rows from a time indexed dataframe

Tags: pandas, dataframe, python-datetime

I want to drop multiple rows from a time indexed dataframe. I already managed to drop one row by using the command below:

df.drop(pd.Timestamp('2023-11-03 10:21:35.050'), inplace = True)

Now I want to drop multiple rows up to a certain datetime. How can I do that?

Comment: pass a list of the indices to drop